What is the solution to this SwiftUI .popover glitch?
Open 'One', then quickly click 'Two' then 'Three'.
You will see 2 & 3 both attempt to open a popover at the same time, resulting in no popup appearing. If you unselect one of them then the other will appear. The red border is just a visual clue to what is going on.
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ControlView(title: "One")
            ControlView(title: "Two")
            ControlView(title: "three")
        }
    }
}

struct ControlView: View {
    let title: String

    @State private var showingPopover = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { showingPopover.toggle() }) {
            Text(title)
                .border(.red, width: showingPopover ? 1 : 0)
        }
        .popover(isPresented: $showingPopover) {
            Text(title)
                .presentationCompactAdaptation(.popover)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    TestView()
}

Video of glitch: https://streamable.com/dod1qc

Could not replicate your issue, all works well for me.
On MacOS 14.5, using Xcode 15.4, tested on real ios 17 devices and macCatalyst. It could be different on older systems. What system are you using/targeting?

MacOS 14.4.1, Xcode 15.3, iOS 17.4 - Happens on iPad more easily than iPhone, on both devices and simulator. You need to tap 2 then 3 quickly while 1 popover is still disappearing.

I added a video of the glitch in action

If it's a serious issue for you then you could always consider a custom popover, see this answer

I think it's an issue for anyone with more than three modals accessible from one screen. Will check that out though thanks.
